# Is it possible to format specific characters inside words?

Tags: support

Is it possible to format letters inside words?

For example, making the first letter in a word bold. When I try this with `**b**old`, I get

**b**old

As you can see, it's italicized, but not bold. `***b***old` gives

***b***old

Is it possible to format letters inside words without extra asterisks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue that was fixed some time around April 2014. See [balpha's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/278094) (he is an SE dev) for more information.

Now you *can* make only the first letter **b**old (`**b**old`), using just asterisks. (Fun fact if you just click the edit button on your question you will see the live markdown now displays correctly.)

However the triple asterisks (`***b***old`) wont work. you have to use `**_b_**old` which will render ***b***old and italics. However if you want an entire word ***bold and italics*** you can use the three asterisks.

Another thing that has changed is underscores in a word are completely ignored. Here_is_an_example_
Yet the same thing with asterisks will display like this: Here*is*an*example*

Comment: I wonder why it only appears in my question when editing.. Did they preserve the old behavior for posts written before a certain date?

Comment: well kind of. The html is actually stored in the database, so if the post is not updated (edited) then the old markdown rendering will stay.

Answer (score 3):

Remember SE supports a strict subset of html. If markdown fails or is  behaving awry, you can always fall back to this.

`<strong><em>b</em></strong>old` gives ***b***old.